# Netbeans 11.3 and Java 14 Preview Features

Tags: java, netbeans, java-14

I am using Java 14 as the default Java platform for Netbeans 11.3 (netbeans_jdkhome is set to my Java 14 JDK) and trying to use a preview feature in a simple Java application.  I set the source level to 14 and set --enable-preview as a compiler argument.  The code compiles without errors.

However, when I try to run it within Netbeans, it complains that the major version of the .class files is 57 while the runtime only plays well with 58 files and preview features.  Here's the error:

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: javaapplicationtest14/JavaApplicationTest14 (class file version 57.65535) was compiled with preview features that are unsupported. This version of the Java Runtime only recognizes preview features for class file version 58.65535

I checked the major version of the .class files and they are indeed 57.  Any ideas why my project won't compile into Java 14 level?  I am using an Ant build.

Comment: Although I can replicate your problem, when I examine the version of my class file using `javap` from the command line, I get `minor version: 65535 major version: 58`, which is what I would expect. How are you determining that your class files truly are version 57?

Comment: I also used javap.  Somehow the problem went away - I think I rebooted my machine or something else "fixed" it; I don't know if my Netbeans installation was using some settings from my previous installation or what...  Really weird, though, in that I do not have Java 13 installed on my system.  I guess I'll never really know what was going on.  But thank you for your input!

Answer (score 4):

As well as setting **--enable-preview** as a compiler option, it should also be set as a *VM Option* when running the code:

[image]

However, that doesn't fix the problem, and unfortunately this looks like a NetBeans 11.3 bug. I reproduced your problem with a *Java with Ant* project, and created Bug Report [NETBEANS-4049 UnsupportedClassVersionError when running JDK14 code with --enable-preview](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-4049).

There are a couple of workarounds if you need to use preview features with JDK 14 in NetBeans:

- Run your application from the command line (with **--enable-preview** as an option) instead of within NetBeans. The same code which fails with the *UnsupportedClassVersionError* in NetBeans runs fine in that environment, which strongly suggests that NetBeans is ignoring the **--enable-preview** run time option.
- Create a *Java with Maven* project instead of a *Java with Ant* project. You can then run your code which uses preview features within NetBeans.

Update your question with more details if you still have problems.

Comment: I did set the option --enable-preview.  The error message I received said that it was only able to execute preview features from class files compiled to Java 14 (major version 58).  Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Right. But if I set **Properties > Sources > Source/Binary/Format** to _JDK 13_, then clean/build I (correctly) get `error: invalid source release 13 with --enable-preview
  (preview language features are only supported for release 14)`. And if  remove --enable-preview, and compile using _JDK 13_ I (correctly) get `error: switch expressions are not supported in -source 13`. NetBeans won't allow me to do the wrong thing no matter how hard I try! So I'm baffled that your class file had `major version 57` (i.e. _JDK 13_). I can't replicate your issue.

Comment: It was weird... but as I mentioned above, it seems to have worked itself out.  I think it may have been more an environment thing with my Ubuntu box.  :shrug:  Thanks for your help and attention to my issue.

Answer (score 4):

### Netbeans Project Configuration (Java 14)

- Java 14
- Netbeans >= 11 (Current: 12.0 LTS)

**Optional**:

> Can use **sdkman** or set default java path:

```
  /opt/<jdk-install-dir>
```

```
C:\Program Files\<jdk-install-dir>
```

#### Project 'Run' Configuration

[image: Project Run Configuration]

#### Java Platform

[image: Build / Compile]

### pom.xml

#### *Notes*

- Check maven.compiler.source / maven.compiler.target
- Check build->plugins->plugin->...-> compilerArgs -> arg

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>Demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>14</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>14</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>--enable-preview</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

nb-javac should not be installed (it appears in the plugins).

If it is installed in 11.3, it seems to create classfiles with version 57 not 58, which the runtime then objects to, as above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying this with Netbeans 15. I want to use the foreign linker API, and code completion is saying:

> MemoryAddress is a preview API and is disabled by default.  (use
> --enable-preview to enable preview APIs)

This is with both JDK 19 and JDK 20 preview. I put the `--enable-preview` option in the `pom.xml` and it doesn't change anything. If I go to project properties / Build / Compile, there are options to choose which JDK but no way to enter JDK options. It seems like `--enable-preview` is recommended by NetBeans hints but there's no way to actually do it. Is this a bug in NB or am I missing something? Very frustrating because I would like to use some of these features and I'm spending my time trying to get my code editor to work. I think this did work in previous versions of NB.